# JavaScript game I'm working on not working

Tags: javascript

RESOLVED: Thanks for the help and explanation!

I'm trying to make this for a game I've been working on, but I'm still new to javascript. Is anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function changeIncome() {
    hr_inc = 5000;
}

var hr_inc;
var sec_inc = hr_inc / 3600;
var wallet;

setInterval(function(){income()},1000);
function income() {
    if (hr_inc !== undefined) {
        if (wallet === undefined) {
            wallet = 0 + sec_inc;
        } else {
            wallet = wallet + sec_inc;
        }       
    } else {
        document.getElementById("income").innerHTML = "No Income";
    }
    document.getElementById("income").innerHTML = wallet.toFixed(2);
}
```

It works at first showing "No Income", but when I try to change the income it returns NaN. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly do you "change the income"?

Comment: `hr_inc` is `undefined`.  `hr_inc / 3600` will give you `NaN`.  `sec_inc` won't magically update once you set `hr_inc`.  You need to update that when you update `hr_inc`.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Sorry for the dumb question :/. I'm still new at this.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the `hr_inc` value, the `sec_inc` value needs to be re-evaluated. Try something like this;

```
function changeIncome() {
    hr_inc = 5000;
    sec_inc = hr_inc / 3600;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the dumb question :/. I'm still new at this.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to evaluate your issue with these information.

First, you have to understand that `sec_inc` is initialised and calculated only once; during the loading of your javascript file.

```
var sec_inc = hr_inc / 3600;
```

If you want to change this value, you have to call within income the calculation.

Where do you call function `changeIncome`? 
You instanciate the function, but you are never calling it

Also, to help you; you should use `console.log` to see some trace of your function.
You can also use Chrome console that is just very handly.

Comment: thanks @rocket Hazmat for update. it even more clear like that.

Comment: You're welcome :-)  I just wanted to clean up the formatting a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I have a button calling it (just for testing purposes)